# SSO/SAML with .NET application

Tags: .net, saml-2.0

*Background*

I have a .NET (not MVC or ASP.NET) application (which is an Excel plugin), which performs 1 REST call for data (REST call is a protected resources - requires authenticated user).
Currently this Excel plugin authenticates with the REST backend using basic authentication (with username/password input fields).
Users are authenticated on a Windows domain.

*Problem*

I want to get rid of the username/password inputs and start using SAML2 to achieve true single signon for these users.from within this .NET application.

***Question 1: Is it possible to perform client-side SAML2 authentication for my app?***

*Which framework/library to use?*

If it is possible (I hope so...), I found this info:

"No is official C# client-side protocol stack", but there are various 3rd party libraries which implement SAML2", but these seem all focused on ASP.NET.

- Sustainsys.Saml2
- OneLogin
- AspNetSaml
- ITfoxtec

I've tried several libraries but they all seem to want to redirect the user (in browser - which I don't use in the app) to a specific endpoint.

I am no .NET guru, so if it is possible, any library with a clear example/tutorial would be really appreciated.

**Followup 2018-12-13**

*So, real SAML authentication is only possible when including a WebBrowserControl in a custom pane in this Excel Add-In application.
This WebBrowserControl will handle the SAML negotiation (including following all redirects etc).
However, I just noticed when I access the URL which triggers the SAML authentication in Firefox (which has empty NTLM trusted URIs) that I get an authentication popup. When I enter my credentials I am authenticated.*

**Question 2**

Can I still perform the SAML negotiation in the .NET backend without the WebBrowserControl, but by supplying the username + password which I currently still have in my GUI?
Can I set the correct headers at some point in the process?
If so, how?

Comment: Show a WebBrowserControl in your application.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be an option. I don't know if the framework I use to build my Excel plugin supports adding a WebBrowserControl in the ribbon.

Are there any alternatives? Is fully native (without browser component) authentication a possibility?

Comment: I strongly doubt it is possible without a browser.

Comment: Ok, after some research the WebBrowserControl really seems the only way to go. How certain are you that this would really work with a WebBrowserControl?

Are there any catches, specific IE versions or OS requirements?

Answer (score 0):

List of [SAML stacks](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Why SAML?

SAML uses browser redirects as you've pointed out.

I would suggest using the [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) libraries i.e. OpenID Connect.